# transpilar angular 2

Tags: javascript, aplicación-web, angularjs-2.0

Si `Angular 2` usa `typescript` cómo transpilo mi proyecto a `ecmascript 5`?
Estoy usando `angular cli` que me genera una estructura de carpetas
he visto que hay una carpeta dist que se genera con el comando **ng build**
pero quiero subir el proyecto a un host pero estoy confudido 
he escuchado de `webPack` pero sigo en la duda debo usar `angular cli` o `webPACK`

Cuál es manera de transpilar a `ecmascript5`?

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Comment: si @juan  ya lo solucione, hace tiempo use angular-cli y webPack.Lo que pasa es no me acordaba de esta pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) es una muy buena opción, pero lo cierto es que nunca he trabajado con el y **TypeScript**, siempre trabajo con **ES6**.

Te recomiendo que le dés un repaso a su web, encontrarás bastante docu. También te dejo [este](http://david-barreto.com/configuring-webpack-with-typescript/) enlace que espero te resulte util.